# IPFS Shared directory

Tags: networking, filesystems

I'd like to setup a shared directory between several nodes using IPFS.

I understand how to read a directory from many peers where only one could change it (the original publisher). I would like all peers to be able to edit the directory.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'll post what I found so far.

The way to share, is always from a publisher's perspective (the peer).
There's no abstraction from the peer that allows multiple peers to publish.

Using the same identity from several hosts is reported to work but it's frowned upon as it's not a supported use case.

A hack to achieve some of this functionality is to share the keys to a IPNS name. That way, different peers could publish to that name, effectively replacing whatever the other peer published.
This could be effective to publish a blog, for example, but it's not a shared directory.